# mod_rewrite and file paths

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, relative-path

I am using mod_rewrite in my haccess to make clean URLs. The working directory is `webroot/subdir` and htaccess resides in `subdir`

What I have works fine for the main folder

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^projects/([0-9]+)$ ?action=projects&id=$1
RewriteRule ^projects ?action=projects

RewriteRule ^clients ?action=clients
RewriteRule ^admins ?action=admins
RewriteRule ^settings ?action=settings
```

so those links would be like `webroot/subdir/projects` or `webroot/subdir/settings` and they work.

My problem occurs on the `projects` line where I have to add an id. When I click a link that says something like: `webroot/subdir/projects/284`, all my style sheets and images break. My CSS is setup like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/buttonPro.css" />
```

Is there a way around this? Am I doing my rewrite rules wrong?

Comment: Better setup virtual host for each project and then create some fake domain name in your `hosts` file (e.g. `project1.dev`). Then you can access your specific project without `/webroot/subdir` prefix. In any case -- @animuson is right about the way how you should define your css/js/images.

Comment: yep, I went ahead and did something like this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/<?php echo INSTALL_DIR; ?>/resources/css/reset.css" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `resources` folder is also in `webroot/subdir`, you need to make your links absolute paths. When the page changes to `projects/([0-9]+)`, your working directory now becomes `webroot/subdir/projects` even though the path is being rewritten, so it is trying to look up your style sheets at `webroot/subdir/projects/resources` which doesn't exist.

Adding a `/` to the beginning of your locations should work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/buttonPro.css" />
```

If your resources folder is outside the home/root directory, you will need to specify the full path to that directory, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webroot/subdir/resources/css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webroot/subdir/resources/css/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webroot/subdir/resources/css/buttonPro.css" />
```

Comment: I tried the `/` in front of the paths which does make it start in webroot. I wanted to avoid having to define what path the `subdir` is since it can be any folder name (this is a webapp people will download and install on their own server). I can add a line to my config.php as to what the directory is and call it from there I suppose.

Comment: @Ronnie: Yes most applications and other software have a line to specify the path for reasons such as this.